# Не добавляется вычисляемое поле в сущность entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть готовая база, в которую ничего вносить нельзя. Я сделал из нее edmx в проекте. Теперь мне нужно добавить вычисляемое поле, которое вычисляет возраст. Добавляю в сущность свойство Age, но вылетает эксепшн.

Код сущности:

```
public partial class Employee
    {
        public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Patronymic { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDay { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                if (BirthDay != null)
                    return (DateTime.Now - BirthDay.Value).Days / 365;
                return 0;
            }
            set { }
        }

    }
```

Сам эксепшн

> The specified type member 'Age' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Как добавить вычисляемое поле в моем случае можно ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от того как использовать это свойство при вызове.

Вот так вы получите ошибку:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    /*         
    FirstOrDefault() применяется к типу IQueryable<Employee>
    В этом случае на стороне БД выполнится примерно такой запрос: 
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Employee]
        WHERE Age = 27
    Но т.к. в таблице нет поля Age то выходит ошибка
    */ 
    var myEmployee = context.Employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Age == 27);
}
```

А вот так ошибки не будет:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    /*
    FirstOrDefault() применяется к типу IEnumerable<Employee>
    В этом случае сначала сервер БД отдаст все элементы из таблицы Employee  
    и только потом клиент (приложение) в памяти посчитает Age.
    */
    var myEmployee = context.Employee.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Age == 27);
}
```